# How do fix MGTwitterStatusesParser / NSXMLParserDelegate issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to compile an iPhone app.  The app is quite old (2.0 SDK) and it is giving me the following error.

`~/Desktop/iphone/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesParser.m:45:0
 ~/Desktop/iphone/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterMessagesParser.m:45: warning:
 'MGTwitterStatusesParser' may not respond to '  parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:'`

I can get past these warnings by turning off the treat warnings as errors but I want to fix it instead.  I saw one post that said he fixed it by "putting in the NSXMLParserDelegate".  Can someone explain exactly what that means or what the best way to resolve this issue is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSXMLParser did not used to have a strict delegate.  e.g. there was not an NSXMLParserDelegate protocol.  Now there is, so in the file MGTwitterXMLParser.h you need to change the line:

```
@interface MGTwitterXMLParser : NSObject {
```

to

```
@interface MGTwitterXMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
```

Comment: @Jasmine It is worth noting that if you are working on Twitter integration now, and you can reasonably drop iOS 4 support (according to the recent keynote at WWDC, iOS 5 has 80% adoption), it is worth looking into the [Twitter Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html) provided by Apple. If you use that, you can be reasonably sure it won't break.